# AS3 Loading Image URLrequest - getBounds returns no values

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I need to get the width and height of a flag I am loading into another movie so I can place it in the right location. Why is my getBounds not picking up the dimensions of the flag?

```
function displayFlags(evt:Event = null)
{
    if(!Lang) { return; }
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < Lang.length; i++)
   {
       //Language = new MovieClip();
       //Language.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton = new button01();
       LangButton.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton.btext.text = Lang[i];
       LangButton.y = LangButton.height * i;
       addChild(LangButton);

       var flag:Loader = new Loader();
       flag.load(new URLRequest(LangPath[i]+"/flag.png"));

       /// Loads Flag into Button          
       LangButton.addChild(flag);

       var fh = flag.getBounds(flag);
       trace("FLAG HEIGHT = " + fh.height); // ZERO ZERO ZERO ZERO

       // I really need this info to place the flag in the right location. 
       flag.y = (LangButton.height/2) - (flag.height/2);     
   }
evt.target.visible = false;
}
```

**UPDATE: MAY 19TH, 2013**

I was able to figure out that I need to wait for the flag to be loaded. Now I can get the correct Bounds.. however, now I can not get the movieClip "flag" in the load complete to respond. I don' think it sees the value of flag.

Below is my UPDATED code:

```
function displayFlags(evt:Event = null)
{
    if(!Lang) { return; }
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < Lang.length; i++)
   {
       //Language = new MovieClip();
       //Language.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton = new button01();
       LangButton.name = Lang[i];
       LangButton.btext.text = Lang[i];
       LangButton.y = LangButton.height * i;
       addChild(LangButton);
       flag = new Loader();
       flag.load(new URLRequest(LangPath[i]+"/flag.png"));
       flag.name = Lang[i];
       flag.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadedFlag(flag));
       function loadedFlag()
       {
           return function()
           {
            var fh = flag.getBounds(flag);

           trace("FLAG HEIGHT = " + fh);
           trace("flag Name: "+ flag.name);

           flag.alpha = .3; 
           }
       } 
       LangButton.addChild(flag);
   }
evt.target.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
flag.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);
```

then add function :

```
function completeHandler(e:Event):void
{
    var myFlagInfo:LoaderInfo = e.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
    var myFlag:Loader = myFlagInfo.loader;
    var fh = myFlag.getBounds(myFlag);
}
```

Comment: This gets the width of the screen and the height keeps on adding with each add of a new Flag. :/

Comment: i do what you code above , i think the flag not loaded yet into button , try to get the bounds after loaded.

Comment: Hello Sameer, I figured this part out on my own but I can't get the flag to be seen now inside my loader complete. :/

Comment: I am able to get the flag.name but I can't get the flag Loader. It just edited the very last flag loaded. I need to access the loader by name but I can't do it in the loaded complete function.

Comment: do you mean , it get just the last flag loader data ?? if that : very easy to solve it . see the edited answer above

Comment: BAM!!! That was exactly it. Awesome. You will get many points on here fast my friend. You know as3 well. Best wishes to you!

Comment: @PapaDeBeau : you are welcome any time , best wishes to you too .